# The Maxwell's Demon and Computer Science

Tags: soft-question, big-picture, it.information-theory, physics

What is the best source -in terms of quality- that would explain the argument that uses computations concepts to demonstrate that the Maxwell's Demon does not break the second law of thermodynamics? I have an impression that this argument has some flaw, because all the sources I know use natural language. However, I would like some source that demonstrates formally.

Comment: Lienhard Pagel in his book "Information ist Energie" gives a quantum mechanical analysis of Maxwell's Demon. He uses his information concept instead of a pure computation concept. If I remember correctly, he explains it both in natural language and with formulas and computations.

Comment: May be these two blog entries of Scott Aaronson are of interest: https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1818  https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=762

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start looking at these ideas is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3533.pdf), though it talks about the (related) idea of information and thermodynamics. It relates fundamental computational tasks (eg. editing a bit) to fundamental thermodynamic tasks (eg. energy extraction). Following the links within the paper should give reasonable access to literature on the subject. Also, see this [paper](https://www.research.ibm.com/people/b/bennetc/bennettc1982666c3d53.pdf).

EDIT - There is also discussion regarding this on Scott Aaronson's blog https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3327. See the comments section too.

References -

[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3533.pdf). The Hot Bit 1 : The Szilard-Landauer Correspondence,
M Gopalkrishnan - arXiv preprint arXiv:1311.3533, 2013

[2](https://www.research.ibm.com/people/b/bennetc/bennettc1982666c3d53.pdf). The Thermodynamics of Computation — a Review, C. Bennet - 
International Journal of Theoretical Physics 21.12 (1982): 905-940.

Comment: Can you please give the references of the papers you cite so your answer remains valid even if the link does not work anymore?

Comment: Good point. Added the references.